# Javascript: display image from JPEG data

Tags: javascript, image

I'm trying to download a jpeg image from a server that requires an API KEY in the headers for authentication.  Then I'd like to display the image.

I believe the download is working, but I can't figure out how to get the image data to display.

Initially I tried to encode the data as base64 and then use "img src="data:image/jpeg;base64" to display it (shown below).  But that isn't working and I'm wondering if canvas is the way to go.  I've searched around and I can't figure out how to load the data into the canvas.

```
    $.ajax
    ({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://my.website.net/index.php/rest/data/5592",
            dataType: 'image/jpeg',
            async: false,

            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-App-Request-Method", "get");
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-App-Request-Key", "XYX");
            },

            success: function (data) {
                    function hexToBase64(str) {
                            return btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, str.replace(/\r|\n/g, "").replace(/([\da-fA-F]{2}) ?/g, "0x$1 ").replace(/ +$/, "").split(" ")));
                            }
                    document.getElementById("image").src = "data:image/jpeg;base64,"+hexToBase64(data);
            }
    });
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("image").src = data` doesn't quite cut it?

Comment: @cerbrus: No - that didn't work.  But I found a way to have the server send a base64-encoded image.  Then I was able to get rid of the hexToBase64 function and just set .src = data.